# Adjust TextView in Layout when TextView is empty

Tags: android, center, textview

I have a basic `ListView` with two `TextViews` in the cells and I would like for the `TextView`s to center to the middle of the `Layout` when there isn't any text in the other `TextView`.

Here is my current XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/detailsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/titleTextView"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using a `RelativeLayout` because I am hoping to utilize it when I add more elements, but I want to figure this part out first. Switching to a LinearLayout didn't have any effect on adjusting the `TextView`s.

Will I have to adjust the views programmatically? If so, how should I handle that? Remove the one view from the layout (Which will require a `LinearLayout`, right)?

Answer (score 2):

Simply make the `TextView` "gone" when it is empty, when a view is "gone" it has no effect on the layout it is in, thus the other `TextView` would center because of the gravity property you have added.

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: So, I will have to constantly be checking and setting the visibility of my `TextView`s cells based on my contents inside my `BaseAdapter`'s `getView` method?

Comment: You can look at this to monitor the `TextView` never used it myself but should make things easy http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged

Comment: Okay. So, I would subclass the TextView in order to get what I want. That makes sense, but it seems pretty heavy for such a simple feature. Maybe this isn't as simple as I would think.

Comment: Putting more thought into it, just put a check it inside `getView` just so much simpler, all that effort isn't worth it

Comment: Its not, since the `onTextChanged` method will be called every time anyways. But its good to know about that conforming method.